# Rust как прочитать содержимое директории?

Tags: rust

Из официальной документации [rust](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/stable/rust-by-example/std_misc/fs.html), есть вот такой пример:

```
use std::fs;
fn main() {
    match fs::read_dir("test") {
        Err(why) => println!("! {:?}", why.kind()),
        Ok(paths) => for path in paths {
            println!("{:?}", path.unwrap().path());
        },
    }
}
```

Подскажите откуда у нас появляет **paths**, и как можно реализовать данный функционал без оператора **match** ?

Comment: Функция read_dir возвращает тип Result, про обработку которого есть соответствующая глава в учебнике https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

Comment: @andreymal, понял, пойду читать документацию )

Answer (score 0):

Вот два варианта реализации моей задачи без оператора **match**:

```
let paths = fs::read_dir("test").expect("Error");
for path in paths {
    println!("{:?}", path.unwrap().path());
};
```

И так:

```
let paths = fs::read_dir("test");
for path in paths.unwrap() {
    println!("{:?}", path.unwrap().path());
};
```